# Can you create parent object and list of children objects in one same form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Im new to django and still learning its full potential. I have two models One is the parent (GoodsReceivedNote) and the other are the items for that note (One to Many). I realize a normal ModelForm is not going to work here as I want the user to be able to enter the details for the parent as well as the children objects.

I looked in to InlineFormSets but as far as I undestood I need to create the parent object first and then assign it to my children. 
Also looked at this link : http://sayhelloworld.co/create-parent-child-model-objects-in-one-form-with-django/ how ever they are using the date to get the recent parent object and add it to the child which doesnt seem the best way

GoodsReceivedNote.py

```py
class Goodsreceivednote(models.Model):
    GOODS_INWARDS = 'INWARDS'
    GOODS_REJECTED = 'REJECTED'
    NOTE_TYPES = (
        (GOODS_INWARDS, GOODS_INWARDS),
        (GOODS_REJECTED, GOODS_REJECTED),
    )
    rec_note_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)  
    note_date = models.DateField()  
    type = models.CharField(choices= NOTE_TYPES, max_length=15, default=GOODS_INWARDS)
```

The Items.py

```py
class Goodsreceiveitem(models.Model):
    received_item_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255) 
    rec_note_id = models.ForeignKey(Goodsreceivednote, models.PROTECT) 
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, models.PROTECT) 
    item_qty = models.IntegerField()
```

[Here is a Sketch of how i expected it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMKtI.png)

Thanks In Advance ! Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ModelForm` for `note` (since there is going to be only 1 note) and `InlineFormSet` for `item` (since you will allow multiple). You don't need to save `note` prior to `items` - you can save them at the same request.

Dynamic adding/deleting `items` require javascript and will not be covered in this answer, however it should be easy enough to understand what django expect to receive.

So, first of all you need to create `ModelForm`:

forms.py:

```py
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Goodsreceivednote
        fields = '__all__'
```

We are going to use `inlineformset_factory` to create `InlineFormSet` for `items`. When saving items, we have to provide parent note to foreign field.

views.py:

```py
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

from .models import Goodsreceivednote, Goodsreceiveitem
from .forms import NoteForm

def note_view(request):
    # Create formset based on our parent model and child model. We are going to allow up to 3 items in form. 
    NoteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Goodsreceivednote, Goodsreceiveitem, fields='__all__', extra=3)

    # generate form and formset
    form = NoteForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    formset = NoteFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        note = form.save()
        for form in formset.forms:
            item = form.save(commit=False)
            item.rec_note_id = note
            item.save()

    return render(request, 'formset.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

formset.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    {{ formset.as_p }}

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Also you don't *have* to specify primary keys in models - they will be automatically generated as `AutoField`. That will decrease some rough parts of models, since you don't have to worry about them being unique.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Tried it out with js works fine. Found django-dynamic-formset to use for the dynamic forms part.